# Server-side Blazor Post using HttpClient with x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: blazor, dotnet-httpclient, blazor-server-side

I am able to use Postman to make a successful Post a request with content type x-www-form-urlencoded to a REST API.
[image: successful post]

However, when I try to make the same post in a Blazor Server-Side app, I get back a 401 error.

The relevant part of my code is as follows:

```
FormUrlEncodedContent content = new(new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                ["qualification_id"] = qualification.QualificationId,
                ["period_id"] = qualification.PeriodId,
                ["taken_date"] = qualification.CompletedDateString,
                ["expiration_date"] = qualification.ExpirationDateString,
            });
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri);
            request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", xApiKey);

            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

            var response = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, content);

            var ret = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<MemberQualification>();

            return ret;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  NB - the API seems to return a 401 error for just about anything including, I think errors that should be 400 - and I am confident that my x-api-key credentials are correct and have been used successfully elsewhere in other httpClient calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `request` is created and filled but not used in any way. That matches the return code (401 Not authorized).

I think you can just use

```
//request.Headers.Add("x-api-key", xApiKey);
  content.Headers.Add("x-api-key", xApiKey);
```

Comment: Het is gelukt - bedankt!